# Determine whether (a, b) = {a, {b, {b}}} can not be a definition of an ordered pair

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please give a counter example to prove that
(a, b) = {a, {b, {b}}}
can not be a definition of an ordered pair.

Comment: I guess it can be used as a definition of ordered pair.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I have post a counter example, please tell me if there is anything wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We want that $(a,b) = \{a,\{b,\{b\}\}\} = \{x,\{y,\{y\}\}\} = (x,y)$ to imply $a=x$ and $b=y$. But taking $y=\varnothing$, $a=\left\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\right\}$, $b=\{\varnothing\}$, $x=\{\{\varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$ demonstrates that this need not be the case.

Comment: Thank you! I testes your answer and it’s right.

Comment: Not a real example if you ask me.

Comment: Just verifying in detail: $\{a,\{b,\{b\}\}\}= 
\{\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\},\{\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}\}$ and 
$\{x,\{y,\{y\}\}\}=\{\{\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\}$. Pretty real to me, @Wuestenfux